# Angularjs - using $http to obtain xml response rather than json

Tags: javascript, html, xml, angularjs

I am trying to scrape a website using angularjs / javascript.

I know that angularjs provides an `$http` object with which I can make get requests. I have previously used this to obtain json, can I use the same object to obtain XML (HTML)? (I believe the response will be encoded using gzip).

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to use `$http` for getting response data other than JSON.  The [`$http` documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) explains that one of the default response transforms is `If JSON response is detected, deserialize it using a JSON parser`.   However if you request something else (for example an HTML template) `response.data` should have the string value of that HTML.   In fact Angular uses `$http` for pulling down HTML for use with `ngInclude`, etc.

The gzip (or unzipping in this case) should be handled by the browser before the response gets to `$http`.

Comment: If you're expecting the passed argument inside the `success` callback to be the `responseXML` property from a native `XMLHttpRequest` based on the file extension or MIME in the response header,  it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Getting an xml file with `$httpProvider` doesn't pass response data into your callback in the form of a DOM.

Use the below example as a pattern, and convert the returned text using the `DOMParser` or appropriate ActiveX object in an old IE client.

```js
exampleModule = angular.module('exampleModule', []);
exampleController = exampleModule.controller('exampleController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("example.xml").then(function (response) {
        var dom;
        if (typeof DOMParser != "undefined") {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            dom = parser.parseFromString(response.data, "text/xml");
        }
        else {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            doc.async = false;
            dom = doc.loadXML(response.data);
        }
        // Now response is a DOMDocument with childNodes etc.
        return dom;
    });
}]);
```